# Voice Memo on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad-app, voice-recording

iPhones have a dedicated iOS "Voice Memos app." iPads don't, despite running the same OS and also featuring a built-in microphone.

What current alternatives do people use on the iPad?

I'm looking for a simple "minimalist" app that works the same way as Voice Memos on the iPhone. The App store lists dozens of apps that are all supposed to do the same thing, so aside from names of apps I'd very much appreciate people who have worked with an app to briefly list the main specs and how it is or is not like iPhone Voice Memos in order not to have to try one by one myself.

There is an [old thread here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44038/what-apps-are-people-using-to-record-voice-meetings-on-the-ipad) asking the same thing, but very incomplete and outdated.